# Is there a custom way to mark faulty digits of approximations?

Tags: numerical-methods, notation

To quantify how bad an estimation is, we can compute its [relative error](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeError.html). I would like to visualize it by marking the faulty digits: is there a customary notation to do so ?